# Calling methods from previous activity in the BackStack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I recently read about Tasks and Back Stack on developer.android.com but I am unclear about something. I have 2 activities, activity A call activity B, the stack it's created with activity A and B, and I discovered that I can still call methods that belongs to activity A in activity B and I can still update the UI from activity A calling its methods in activity B. And I'm worried if this is a safe approach. I'm afraid that activity A may be destroyed at a given point and if I try to call a method that belong to activity A in activity B then it may throw me an exception.

Comment: How do you call methods of Activity A in Activity B?

Comment: Activity A implements an interface, but I saw that it works just by creating a static method in Activity A and then in Activity B just to: ActivityA.method().

Comment: Since it's a static method, it has nothing to do with the fields of Activity A. Only things to worry is the state of the static variables of Activity A , I guess it may produce potential bugs under some circumstances.

Comment: But about the interface that is implemented by Activity A, it's this a right way to call methods like that from A in B, making use of the interface? Since they're in the same stack.

Comment: In fact, i'm confused about this. A interface method cannot be a static method. If it's not a static method, there's no way to call it without holding the reference of an ActivityA instance. Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: The process is much complex than you think actually. I'm making a music player and I'm using the service class (which handle the music stuff) to communicate between both activites since music service is used in both activities, I can call a method from music service which calls another method from MyInterface which is implements by Activity A. And I'm passing that reference of Activity A on the MusicService class at onCreate's Activity A method. MusicService has a static method to pass the reference, it's called, setMainActivityAccess(Activity activity).

Comment: And then I can just do in Activity B: musicSerice.callActivityAMethod() and then it will call interfaceObj.methodOfActiviyA().
interfaceObj = activity (passed by setMainActivityAccess method to the service class).